# Same function as weather app in ios 5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5

Ok, I have had a request to implement the same function that the weather app on ios 5 has. Where when you select the current day it drops down to reveal the hourly weather forecast. Has anyone any ideas on how this is done? or can you point me in the direction of some example code? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this would be done by adding rows to the table view when a cell is selected, this could be done by adding another section, or changing the row count.

you would do this in a begin and end updates block:

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

you should make sure that when you do this you're table view data source methods return appropriate values for the number of rows and sections.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the `UITableView` method

```
insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:
```

When the user taps on a cell, call that method to insert new rows in the table as required. Of course, your data source will need to return rows for the inserted rows.